# Dictionary based non-local mean implementation in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, array, error-handling, matrix, matlab

Given a dictionary including multiple X-Y pairs where X, Y are both three dimensional structure. `dictionaryBasedNonlocalMean` function return a `output` which is weighted sum of each Y in the dictionary. Each weight of Y are based on the Manhattan distance between the `input` of `dictionaryBasedNonlocalMean` function and the corresponding X in the dictionary. In mathematical form, output is calculated with the following way.

$$output = K\sum_{{i = 1}}^{{N}_{D}} \left[ G_{\mu = 0, \sigma} (\left\|input - X(i)\right\|_{1}) \cdot Y(i) \right]
$$

where N<sub>D</sub> is the count of X-Y pairs (the cardinality of set X and set Y) in the dictionary and the Gaussian function

$$G_{\mu = 0, \sigma} (\left\|input - X(i)\right\|_{1}) = \left.e^{\frac{-(\left\|input - X(i)\right\|_{1} - \mu)^2}{2 {\sigma}^{2}}}\right|_{\mu=0}
$$

Moreover, K is a normalization factor

$$K = \frac{1}{\sum_{{i = 1}}^{{N}_{D}} G_{\mu = 0, \sigma} (\left\|input - X(i)\right\|_{1})}
$$

[image: Illustration]

**The experimental implementation**

- `ManhattanDistance` function

  ```
  function output = ManhattanDistance(X1, X2)
      output = sum(abs(X1 - X2), 'all');
  end
  ```
- `dictionaryBasedNonlocalMean` function

  ```
  function [output] = dictionaryBasedNonlocalMean(Dictionary, input)
      gaussian_sigma = 0.1;
      gaussian_mean = 0;
      if size(Dictionary.X) ~= size(Dictionary.Y)
          disp("Size of data in dictionary incorrect.");
          output = [];
          return
      end
      [X, Y, Z, DataCount] = size(Dictionary.X);
      weightOfEach = zeros(1, DataCount);
      for i = 1:DataCount
          %   Gaussian of distance between X and input
          weightOfEach(i) = gaussmf(ManhattanDistance(input, Dictionary.X(:, :, :, i)), [gaussian_sigma gaussian_mean]);  
      end
      sumOfDist = sum(weightOfEach, 'all');
      output = zeros(X, Y, Z);
      %%% if sumOfDist too small
      if (sumOfDist < 1e-160)
          fprintf("sumOfDist = %d\n", sumOfDist);
          return;
      end
      for i = 1:DataCount
          output = output + Dictionary.Y(:, :, :, i) .* weightOfEach(i);
      end
      output = output ./ sumOfDist;
  end
  ```

**Test case**

```
ND = 10;
xsize = 8;
ysize = 8;
zsize = 1;
Dictionary = CreateDictionary(ND, xsize, ysize, zsize);
output = dictionaryBasedNonlocalMean(Dictionary, ones(xsize, ysize, zsize) .* 0.66)

function Dictionary = CreateDictionary(ND, xsize, ysize, zsize)
    Dictionary.X = zeros(xsize, ysize, zsize, ND);
    Dictionary.Y = zeros(xsize, ysize, zsize, ND);
    for i = 1:ND
        Dictionary.X(:, :, :, i) = ones(xsize, ysize, zsize) .* (i / ND);
        Dictionary.Y(:, :, :, i) = ones(xsize, ysize, zsize) .* (1 + i / ND);
    end
end
```

The output result of testing code above:

```
output =

    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622    1.6622
```

All suggestions are welcome.