# Calculate distances between two multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab

Tags: array, error-handling, matrix, matlab

In question ["Dictionary based non-local mean implementation in Matlab"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268454/231235), the Manhattan distance between two three-dimensional structures can be calculated by `ManhattanDistance` function. In this post, besides Manhattan distance, the functions for calculating Euclidean distance, squared Euclidean distance and maximum distance are presented here.

In mathematical form, Euclidean distance of two three-dimensional inputs *X<sub>1</sub>* and *X<sub>2</sub>* with size N<sub>1</sub> x N<sub>2</sub> x N<sub>3</sub> is defined as

$$
\begin{split}
D_{Euclidean}(X_{1}, X_{2}) & = \left\|X_{1} - X_{2}\right\|_{2} \\
        & = \sqrt{\sum_{k_{1} = 1}^{N_{1}} \sum_{k_{2} = 1}^{N_{2}} \sum_{k_{3} = 1}^{N_{3}} {( X_{1}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) - X_{2}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) )}^{2}}
\end{split}
$$

Squared Euclidean distance of two three-dimensional inputs *X<sub>1</sub>* and *X<sub>2</sub>* with size N<sub>1</sub> x N<sub>2</sub> x N<sub>3</sub> is defined as

$$
\begin{split}
D_{Euclidean}^{2}(X_{1}, X_{2}) & = \left\|X_{1} - X_{2}\right\|_{2}^{2} \\
& =  \sum_{k_{1} = 1}^{N_{1}} \sum_{k_{2} = 1}^{N_{2}} \sum_{k_{3} = 1}^{N_{3}} {( X_{1}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) - X_{2}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) )}^{2}
\end{split}
$$

Maximum distance of two three-dimensional inputs *X<sub>1</sub>* and *X<sub>2</sub>* with size N<sub>1</sub> x N<sub>2</sub> x N<sub>3</sub> is defined as

$$
\begin{split}
D_{Maximum}(X_{1}, X_{2}) & = \left\|X_{1} - X_{2}\right\|_{\infty} \\
& = \max_{k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}} {( X_{1}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) - X_{2}(k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}) )}
\end{split}
$$

**The experimental implementation**

- `EuclideanDistance` function: for calculating Euclidean distance between two inputs

  ```
  function [output] = EuclideanDistance(X1, X2)
  %EUCLIDEANDISTANCE Calculate Euclidean distance between two inputs
      if size(X1)~=size(X2)
          fprintf("Sizes of inputs are not equal!\n");
          return;
      end
      output = sqrt(SquaredEuclideanDistance(X1, X2));
  end
  ```
- `SquaredEuclideanDistance` function: for calculating squared Euclidean distance between two inputs

  ```
  function [output] = SquaredEuclideanDistance(X1, X2)
  %SQUAREDEUCLIDEANDISTANCE Calculate squared Euclidean distance between two inputs
      if size(X1)~=size(X2)
          fprintf("Sizes of inputs are not equal!\n");
          return;
      end
      output = sum((X1 - X2).^2, 'all');
  end
  ```
- `MaximumDistance` function: for calculating maximum distance between two inputs

  ```
  function [output] = MaximumDistance(X1, X2)
  %MAXIMUMDISTANCE Calculate maximum distance between two inputs
      if size(X1)~=size(X2)
          fprintf("Sizes of inputs are not equal!\n");
          return;
      end
      output = max(X1 - X2, [], 'all');
  end
  ```

**Test case**

```
%%  Three-dimensional test case
fprintf("Three-dimensional test case\n");
SizeNum = 8;
A = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.2;
B = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.1;

ED = EuclideanDistance(A, B)
MD = MaximumDistance(A, B)
SED = SquaredEuclideanDistance(A, B)

%%  Four-dimensional test case
fprintf("Four-dimensional test case\n");
SizeNum = 8;
A = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.2;
B = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.1;

ED = EuclideanDistance(A, B)
MD = MaximumDistance(A, B)
SED = SquaredEuclideanDistance(A, B)

%%  Five-dimensional test case
fprintf("Five-dimensional test case\n");
SizeNum = 8;
A = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.2;
B = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.1;

ED = EuclideanDistance(A, B)
MD = MaximumDistance(A, B)
SED = SquaredEuclideanDistance(A, B)

%%  Six-dimensional test case
fprintf("Six-dimensional test case\n");
SizeNum = 8;
A = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.2;
B = ones(SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum, SizeNum) .* 0.1;

ED = EuclideanDistance(A, B)
MD = MaximumDistance(A, B)
SED = SquaredEuclideanDistance(A, B)
```

The output result of testing code above:

```
Three-dimensional test case

ED =

    2.2627


MD =

    0.1000


SED =

    5.1200

Four-dimensional test case

ED =

    6.4000


MD =

    0.1000


SED =

   40.9600

Five-dimensional test case

ED =

   18.1019


MD =

    0.1000


SED =

  327.6800

Six-dimensional test case

ED =

   51.2000


MD =

    0.1000


SED =

   2.6214e+03
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test cases don’t test the error condition handling:

```matlab
if size(X1)~=size(X2)
    fprintf("Sizes of inputs are not equal!\n");
    return;
end
```

In the case of two inputs with different dimensionality, you will see an error message saying you’re comparing vectors of different length. This is because `size` will return, say a 1x2 matrix and a 1x3 matrix, and you cannot compare those with `~=`, that operator requires equal-size arrays.

In case of two inputs with the same number of dimensions but different sizes, you will see your message printed to screen, and then an error that the output argument was not assigned a value. This is because you return without assigning to `output`.

If there is an error condition, you should use `error` to flag it. You can’t produce an output value and have calling code continue to process normally. Throw an error and either have the calling code handle it or the program stop altogether.

The proper way to test for equal input sizes is as follows:

```matlab
if ~isequal(size(X1), size(X2))
   error('Sizes of inputs are not equal!')
end
```

`isequal` will return false if the two arrays are of different size or do not have equal values.

You could also use `assert`, or [the new input parameter specification system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/input-and-output-arguments.html).