# Mean and variance of element-wise distances in a set of multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab

Tags: array, multithreading, matlab

This is a follow-up question for [Calculate distances between two multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268829/231235). Given a set S<sub>X</sub>

$$
S_{X} = \{ { X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, \dots, X_{n} } \}
$$

where n is the count of elements in set S<sub>X</sub> (the cardinality of set S<sub>X</sub>)

There are $${{ n }\choose{2}}$$ element-wise distances in set S<sub>X</sub>.

The mean and variance of these element-wise distances can be calculated with `AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` and `VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` functions.

**Example**

```
%%  Preparing data

DataCount = 10;
sizex = 8;
sizey = 8;
sizez = 8;
Collection = ones(sizex, sizey, sizez, DataCount);
for i = 1:DataCount
    Collection(:, :, :, i) = ones(sizex, sizey, sizez) .* i;
end

%%  Function testing

AIED = AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(Collection)
VIED = VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(Collection)
```

The output result of example above:

```
AIED =

   82.9672


VIED =

   4.0328e+03
```

**The experimental implementation**

- `AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` function

  ```
  function [output] = AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(X1)
      D = 0;
      for i = 1:size(X1, 4)
          element1 = X1(:, :, :, i);
          parfor j = i:size(X1, 4)
              element2 = X1(:, :, :, j);
              D = D + EuclideanDistance(element1, element2);
          end
      end
      k = 2;
      NormalizationFactor = (1 / nchoosek(size(X1, 4), k));
      output = NormalizationFactor * D;
  end
  ```
- `VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` function

  ```
  function [output] = VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(X1)
      Avg = AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(X1);
      D = 0;
      for i = 1:size(X1, 4)
          element1 = X1(:, :, :, i);
          for j = i:size(X1, 4)
              element2 = X1(:, :, :, j);
              D = D + (EuclideanDistance(element1, element2) - Avg)^2;
          end
      end
      k = 2;
      NormalizationFactor = ( 1 / nchoosek(size(X1, 4), k));
      output = NormalizationFactor * D;
  end
  ```
- `EuclideanDistance` function

  ```
  function [output] = EuclideanDistance(X1, X2)
  %EUCLIDEANDISTANCE Calculate Euclidean distance between two inputs
      if ~isequal(size(X1), size(X2))
        error('Sizes of inputs are not equal!')
      end
      output = sqrt(SquaredEuclideanDistance(X1, X2));
  end
  ```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Calculate distances between two multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268829/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` and `VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` functions in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only comment here is that

```matlab
AIED = AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(Collection)
VIED = VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar(Collection)
```

computes the average twice, since `VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` also calls `AverageIntraEuclideanDistancesPar`. I would suggest writing a function that returns both the average and the variance.

That said, your way of computing variance is precise, but expensive because it computes the distances twice, first to determine the mean, and then again to determine the variance. I suggest you read [this Wikipedia article on computing variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). Depending on the properties of the input, either the naive algorithm or Welford’s could be used.

Three more details:

- `VarIntraEuclideanDistancesPar` had “par” in the name, but doesn’t actually do its computation in parallel.
- `parfor` should ideally be the outer loop, not the inner one. Starting up a parallel computation had overhead, you want to limit this overhead as much as possible.
- Reshaping the arrays to be 2D would make your indexing operations simpler and easier to read. Reshaping is an essentially free operation.