# Mean and variance of element-wise distances in a set of multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab - follow-up

Tags: performance, algorithm, array, combinatorics, matlab

This is a follow-up question for [Calculate distances between two multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268829/231235) and [Mean and variance of element-wise distances in a set of multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269052/231235). For avoiding calculating distances and average twice, I am trying to propose a different implementation which is to calculate all distances first and then calculate mean and variance.

**The experimental implementation**

- `MeanVarIntraEuclideanDistances` function

  ```
  function [Mean, Variance] = MeanVarIntraEuclideanDistances(X1)
      Distances = IntraEuclideanDistances(X1);
      k = 2;
      NormalizationFactor = (1 / nchoosek(size(X1, 4), k));
      Mean = sum(Distances, 'all') * NormalizationFactor;
      Variance = sum((Distances - Mean).^2, 'all') * NormalizationFactor;
  end
  ```
- `IntraEuclideanDistances` function: returns the element-wise distances in an array

  ```
  function Distances = IntraEuclideanDistances(X1)
      N = size(X1, 4);
      Distances = zeros(1, N * (N - 1) / 2);
      for i = 1:N
          element1 = X1(:, :, :, i);
          for j = i:N
              element2 = X1(:, :, :, j);
              DistIndex = (N + (N - (i - 1) + 1)) * (i - 1) / 2 + (j - i + 1);
              Distances(DistIndex) = EuclideanDistance(element1, element2);
          end
      end
  end
  ```
- `EuclideanDistance` function

  ```
  function [output] = EuclideanDistance(X1, X2)
  %EUCLIDEANDISTANCE Calculate Euclidean distance between two inputs
      if ~isequal(size(X1), size(X2))
        error('Sizes of inputs are not equal!')
      end
      output = sqrt(SquaredEuclideanDistance(X1, X2));
  end
  ```
- `SquaredEuclideanDistance` function

  ```
  function [output] = SquaredEuclideanDistance(X1, X2)
  %SQUAREDEUCLIDEANDISTANCE Calculate squared Euclidean distance between two inputs
      if ~isequal(size(X1), size(X2))
          error('Sizes of inputs are not equal!')
      end
      output = sum((X1 - X2).^2, 'all');
  end
  ```

**Test case**

```
%%  Preparing data

DataCount = 10;
sizex = 8;
sizey = 8;
sizez = 8;
Collection = ones(sizex, sizey, sizez, DataCount);
for i = 1:DataCount
    Collection(:, :, :, i) = ones(sizex, sizey, sizez) .* i;
end

%%  Function testing

[Mean, Variance] = MeanVarIntraEuclideanDistances(Collection)
```

The output of test case:

```
Mean =

   82.9672


Variance =

   4.0328e+03
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Calculate distances between two multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268829/231235) and

  [Mean and variance of element-wise distances in a set of multi-dimensional arrays in Matlab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269052/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to propose a different implementation which is to calculate all distances first and then calculate mean and variance in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.